# Rails form validation is not working with and update - view has a form and partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view that calls a complaint form. It also happens to have a partial on the same page.

If I create a new complaint the validation works as intended. However, if I delete the contents of a validated field during an update and try to update/save, I get a crash/error but I am not getting any validation errors.

```
class Complaint < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer, :class_name => 'Customer', :foreign_key => 'customer_id'

  has_many :attachments, :dependent => :destroy
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments

  has_many :document_histories #, :dependent => destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :document_histories

# has_one :user
  has_many :users, :through => :document_histories

  validate :resolution_must_be_in_the_future
  validates_presence_of :status
  validates_presence_of :sales_order
  validates_presence_of :product_name
  validates_presence_of :coater_roll_number
  validates_presence_of :coater_work_order
  validates_presence_of :slitter_disposition
  validates_presence_of :length
  validates_presence_of :measure
  validates_presence_of :disposition
  validates_presence_of :reason_for_complaint
  validates_presence_of :customer
  after_initialize :init

  def init
      if self.new_record? && self.status.nil?     # see if it's a new record and if it is nill
        self.status = 'New'                       # Set status - NOTE - in this case we used a dropbox collection so the setting should be something in the dropbox .
      end
    end

  def resolution_must_be_in_the_future
    errors.add(:resolution_date, "must be in the future") if
        !requested_resolution_date.blank? && requested_resolution_date < Date.today  && self.new_record?
  end


end
```

Here are two of the fields in my complaints form. There are, of course, more fields.

```
<div class="field">
    <strong><%= f.label :slitter_disposition %></strong><br>
    <%= f.text_area :slitter_disposition, :rows => 10, :cols => 120 %>


  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <strong><%= f.label :reason_for_complaint %></strong><br>
    <%= f.text_area :reason_for_complaint, :rows => 5, :cols => 120 %>
  </div>
```

If I delete the contents of any validated field while doing an update, I get an error of the following. In this case

```
NoMethodError in Complaints#update
Showing C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/internal_complaints/app/views/complaints/_form.html.erb where line #41 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/complaints/edit.html.erb

Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/internal_complaints

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/complaints/_form.html.erb:41:in `block in _app_views_complaints__form_html_erb__591273067_68586864'
app/views/complaints/_form.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_complaints__form_html_erb__591273067_68586864'
app/views/complaints/edit.html.erb:89:in `_app_views_complaints_edit_html_erb__1060012553_73607220'
app/controllers/complaints_controller.rb:177:in `block (2 levels) in update'
app/controllers/complaints_controller.rb:160:in `update'
Request

Parameters:

{... removed irrelevent parameters
 "reason_for_complaint"=>"",
```

My log file shows..

```
  Rendered complaints/_form.html.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendered complaints/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (22.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 35ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
    40:                     -->
    41: 
    42:           <% if action_name != "new" && action_name != "create" then %>
    43:               <%=  @user.name %>
    44:           <% else %>
    45:               <%= @current_user.name %>
    46:                   <%= f.hidden_field(:user_id, :value => @current_user.id) %>
  app/views/complaints/_form.html.erb:43:in `block in _app_views_complaints__form_html_erb__591273067_73900308'
  app/views/complaints/_form.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_complaints__form_html_erb__591273067_73900308'
  app/views/complaints/edit.html.erb:89:in `_app_views_complaints_edit_html_erb__1060012553_73607220'
  app/controllers/complaints_controller.rb:177:in `block (2 levels) in update'
  app/controllers/complaints_controller.rb:160:in `update'
```

No matter what field I leave blank, the error will always point to the same line as above. How can I ensure that the Rails validation works when I am doing an update?

-------------- Edit

If I remark out the validation for the field that is empty, then the update process without error. i.e if I remark out the line

```
#  validates_presence_of :reason_for_complaint
```

then the form will process and the field will be blank in the table. The problem is that the validations are needed

------------------------ Edit 2

Here is the code where I'm getting the error. The code is not supposed to execute if it is a new complaint. It does not execute when there is an update with no validation errors. It appears that validation errors are causing the form to think it is new/create not edit/update.

```
<td>
              <% if action_name != "new" && action_name != "create" then %>
                  <% $document_assign = @complaint.id %>
                  <% $sent_by_name = $current_user_name %>
                  <% $sent_by_login = @user.login %>
               <% end %>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there are a couple of potential issues here, and without more code, it's hard to tell how the validation plays into it.

Let's first look at your server log.  What it seems to be telling us is this:  Your code is trying to call `.name` on nil -- which is no good.

This line, is the line it is borking on:
`app/views/complaints/_form.html.erb:43:in block in`     `_app_views_complaints__form_html_erb__591273067_73900308'`

If we take a look at line 43 in your template code, it looks like you are trying to call `.name` on `@user`.  OK, so that means, `@user` is nil at that point. Weird. Why would that be?

So, your first order of business is determining why would `@user` be nil at that point? Have you had a chance to step through your controller code and assure yourself that you are setting the `@user` variable before you send it out to the View?

Comment: I think I see what is happening. I added the surrounding code back in my original post. The code where I am getting an error is not supposed to execute when I am doing an edit/update, however, it is executing when I have a validation failure. I'm looking at the edit and update controllers now.

Answer (score 0):

@queserasera got me pointed in the correct direction. It appears that in the event of a validation failure, I need to set some variables/parameters that were in the edit controller in the create controller also. One of those happened to be @user.

I added the following to def user.

```
  @users = User.uniq.pluck(:name)
    @complaint = Complaint.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(@complaint.user_id)     # this points the complaint to the appropriate user record.

    @existing_sent_to = DocumentHistory.where(:complaint_id => $document_assign)
    $existing_sent_to = DocumentHistory.where(:complaint_id => $document_assign)

    @attachments = @complaint.attachments
    @user = User.find(@complaint.user_id)     # this points the complaint to the appropriate user record.

    # Grab the current complaint id, put it in $current_record_id.  Then use that in the where clause.
    # to show the document histories for the current record
    $current_record_id = @complaint.id
    $document_histories = DocumentHistory.where(["complaint_id like ?", "%#{$current_record_id}%"])
```

That seems to have resolved the issue. I still need to test this but I think it is working ok. I am no longer getting the error screen on a failed validation. I am simply getting the edit form with the rails validation messages.